# c# get value of json object by referencing another value in the same json file

Tags: c#, json

I need to read a value from a JSON file but the mode name will depend on the locale language. The JSON node is:

```
"title": {
        "en_GB": "Raj Garden"
    }
```

but the key "en_GB" will depend on the language locale used. This is specified in another node in the same file:

```
"locale": "en_GB"
```

I can read the locale value and the title value but I would like to replace the hard coded title.en_GB with a dynamic value.

```
string locale = Wix.restaurant.locale;
var title = Wix.restaurant.title.en_GB;
```

I think that I need something like:
string name = Wix.restaurant.title..GetType().GetProperty(locale).GetValue(object);

but I don't know how to specify the object. I hope that you can help. Many thanks

Comment: How do you get Wix.restaurant.locale ? You don't mention how do you read/parse json. This may be the key because JSON parsers sometimes offers hooks to convert data

Comment: You probably want a `Dictionary<string, string>` as the type for `title`

Comment: I used https://jsonutils.com/ to create the C# classes. It created a class . public class for the title: Title
    {
        public string en_GB { get; set; }
    } and this is used by the Restaurant class : public Title title { get; set; }

Comment: You still don't tell how to you read the json. How do you convert from string or stream to your custom objects ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Steve B. I used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json); to read the json values into a model that contains that contains classes for each json node.

Comment: If you use `Newtonsoft.Json` you may try to create a custom converter that will allow you to hook the deserialization of a specific part of your json structure. The idea is to use this converter to hook the parsing of the "title" property, and select the specific sub property to choose the correct translation.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by my lack of understanding of the classes correctly returned by  jsonutils.com. It returned as class:

```
public class Title
{
    public string en_GB { get; set; }
}
```

and I thought that the string en_GB would change depending on the locale used. But en_GB is just the name of the string, and will not depend on the locale used in the JSON file. The fix was to simply change the string name:

```
public class Title
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON file is correctly deserialized

```
"title": {
        "en_GB": "Flavour of Asia"
    }
```

The value "Flavour of Asia" is returned in Title.name

Schoolboy error... Thanks to @Steve B and @Charlieface for the replies